# Nagios Monitoring Via a Bastion Box

Tags: ssh-tunneling, nagios

I have a bastion server that has access to 50 machines running different Linux systems. I also have a separate Nagios server that has access to the bastion box. Is it possible to monitor the 50 machines via an ssh tunnel in the following manner:

Nagios box - [ssh tunnel] -> bastion box - [ssh tunnels 1....50] - Linux machines

There is no other direct connection to the 50 hosts from the Nagios box.

Comment: Seems like there's a way: https://support.nagios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=40619

Answer (score 0):

Several check_commands are called with the $HOSTADRESS argument in `checkcommands.cfg` in a "standard" configuration, as in:

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_ping -H 10.1.1.2 -w 100.0,20% -c 500.0,60% -p 5
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 10.1.1.3 -c checkMEM -a ShowAll type=physical type=page type=virtual MaxWarn=90% MaxCrit=95%
```

So the actual file:

```
define command{
    command_name    check_nrpe
    command_line    $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c $ARG1$
}
```

Either you define here something like (have not tested it):

```
define command{
    command_name    check_nrpe
    command_line    ssh $HOSTADDRESS$ "$USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c $ARG1$"
}
```

Or your write a (very) ugly hack creating a shell wrapper to a couple of commands living under `/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/´, namely`/usr/lib/nagios/check_nrpe`, and then do diversions in Debian.

You will probably need more changes than this; if you do nrpe on top of ssh or similar, you won't need SSL on it.